# Nginx multiple IPs to origin

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I need to set up Nginx as a reverse proxy to my origin. The origin has a restriction of **50 concurrent HTTP connections per IP address**.

My Ubuntu server has multiple IPs attached to it. I want to use these IPs to achieve more than 50 concurrent requests to my origin.

Below is how I am trying to do it. I have created multiple server blocks where each block listens on a particular IP. I have also added the public IPs in the DNS records to achieve round-robin DNS.

Now, If I have 3 nginx "server" blocks as follows. I am hoping that a different IP will be sent to my origin based on the server block used to make the request? So, I will be able to achieve theoretically, 150 concurrent requests (if there were 50 people resolving DNS to each IP).

Please let me know if my setup is correct?

```
 server {

            listen 1.1.1.1:80;
            server_name proxy.site.net;
            proxy_pass https://example.com/
            proxy_bind 1.1.1.1 transparent;
 }
 
  server {

            listen 1.1.1.2:80;
            server_name proxy.site.net;
            proxy_pass https://example.com/
            proxy_bind 1.1.1.2 transparent;
 }
 
  server {

            listen 1.1.1.3:80;
            server_name proxy.site.net;
            proxy_pass https://example.com/
            proxy_bind 1.1.1.3 transparent;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `listen` directive multiple times in the server block

Sample Config

```
 server {

            listen 1.1.1.1:80;
            listen 1.1.1.2:80;
            listen 1.1.1.3:80;

            server_name proxy.site.net;
            proxy_pass https://example.com/
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. So I am assuming that the client resolves to 1.1.1.1 will achieve 50 concurrent connections to the origin because 1.1.1.1 will be sent to the origin by the Niginx. Similarly 1.1.1.2 and 1.1.1.3. So my assumption is correct that I can achieve more than 50 concurrent connections to origin using this method?

Comment: Just "proxy_bind" directive in my code. As I think it is needed to forward the IP to origin. Let me know if I can have multiple proxy_bind in the same server block?